# show that there are at least $n/4$ odd numbers and at least $n/4$ even numbers.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

For a nonzero integer $k$, denote by $\nu_2(k)$ the maximal nonnegative integer $t$ such that $2^t \mid k$. Given are $n (\ge 2)$ pairwise distinct integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. Show that there exists an integer $x$, distinct from $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, such that among $$\nu_2(x - a_1), \ldots, \nu_2(x - a_n)$$there are at least $n/4$ odd numbers and at least $n/4$ even numbers.

The problem seems to be the use of mathematical induction or the use of anyway, but I have no idea about this problem(it's from a school exam ），Thanks

Comment: Where'd you find this problem, out of curiosity?

Comment: it's exam few days ago.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I just surmised the source of the problem, from the user's profile.  He is from the future, and in our/his timeline, the person that solves/solved this problem is a mathSE reviewer.

Comment: If all the $a_i$s are odd, you might as well subtract $1$ from all of them as the variable $x$ can absorb that. Then the $a_i$s are all even when we need to use an even $x$ for otherwise $\nu_2(x-a_i)=0$ for all $i$. Implying that we might as well divide all the $a_i$s by two; something we could do right away, if all the $a_i$s were even. So without loss of generality we can assume that some of the $a_i$s are odd and some are even (rinse and repeat as the case may be). Don't know if this helps :-(

Comment: But what kind of a "school" uses contest math problems in the exams. That has been a bit phony in many of your questions. The math is interesting, but lack of openess/honesty about the source gives a bad vibe.

Comment: Anyway, I would approach the question from a bit pigeon-hole direction, trying to decide on a choice of $x$ one bit at a time.

Comment: It's a middle school in China, this school has a special competition class, once a week examination, this question comes from an examination, but I did not see the answer, so consult here

Comment: Once a week is too frequent.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1371199p7555554